# I don't know why my code is giving wrong answer

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array A of 0s and 1s, we may change up to K values from 0 to 1.

> Return the length of the longest (contiguous) subarray that contains only 1s.

> Example 1:

```
Input: A = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0], K = 2
Output: 6
Explanation: 
[1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
Bolded numbers were flipped from 0 to 1.  The longest subarray is underlined.
```

> Example 2:

```
Input: A = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1], K = 3
Output: 10
Explanation: 
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
Bolded numbers were flipped from 0 to 1.  The longest subarray is underlined.
```

> Note:

```
1 <= A.length <= 20000
0 <= K <= A.length
A[i] is 0 or 1
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones-iii/

This is the question link. On the first test case, I am getting output 9 but it should be 6. I can't figure out where it is going wrong?

```
 public static int f(int arr[],int n,int tar)
 {
   
    int st=0,maxc=0,maxf=0;
    //tar=tar+1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int se=i-st-maxc;
        if(arr[i]==1)
       maxc++;
        while(i-st-maxc>tar)
        {
            maxf=Math.max(maxf, i-st);
            st++;
        }
       
    }
    return maxf+1;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner p=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n,target;
    n=p.nextInt();
    target=p.nextInt();
    int arr[]=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=p.nextInt();
    }
    int ans=f(arr,n,target);
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: yes. it is entering the while loop when (i-st-maxc=tar). but that doesn't satisfy the condition .

Comment: Please elaborate that by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Please turn the shown code into a [mre] which processes specifically the failing test case and demonstrats the behaviour you observed and describe. Explain specifically in which way the observed behaviour of your code contradicts the goal. You might want to quote at least those parts of the goal which are confliciting and rephrase them, in order to allow spotting misunderstanding you have about the goal.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use long names and `final` intermediate variables to clarify your code, the compiler generally removes them anyway. For example, exactly what does `i-st-maxc>tar` mean? Also, looks like you're coming from a C or C++ background, Java arrays include their size so you don't need to pass in `n`, use `arr.length`.

Comment: @DEBANJANBHATTACHARJEE will you please explian how you gonna try to solve that problem. First we want to understand your thinking then we can help you to solve it on your own.

Comment: First of all I checked is there any 1 or not in the array. if 1 is present then I am increasing the count. Now if i-st-count (i = my current position , st = leftmost position of the array, and maximum count count)is greater than the my target the I am increasing the leftmost position (sliding window approach),until i != size of the array

Comment: Your solution producing 11 for 1st case, how are you getting 9? Is your solution posted here different from what you might be running?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to provide the size of the array because you can get the size from the array.
If you use better variable names, the readability of the code will be better.
Also, you can use if statements in order to check changed values instead of counting.

This is example of the solution:

```
  public static int longestOnes(int[] A, int K) {
    var maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      var count = 0;
      var k = 0;
      for (int j = i; j < A.length; j++) {
        if (A[j] == 1) {
          count++;
        }
        if (A[j] == 0) {
          if (k >= K) {
            if (count > maxCount) {
              maxCount = count;
            }
            break;
          }
          count++;
          k++;
        }
      }
    }
    return maxCount;
  }
```

Comment: Why is your code the solution?  What's it doing differently than the OP's code?  An explanation would help everyone reading this question and answer.